# SQLSERVER autenticação windows

Tags: sql-server

Estou tentando conectar ao SQLSERVER 2012 com autenticação windows e ele me mostra esse erro, tenho dois servidores criados, testei os dois mas não deu certo, antes quando usei ele conectou.

### `TÍTULO: Conectar ao Servidor

Não é possível conectar-se a ROMULO\MSSQLSERVER_TEST.

---

INFORMAÇÕES ADICIONAIS:

Erro de rede ou específico à instância ao estabelecer conexão com o SQL Server. O servidor não foi encontrado ou não estava acessível. Verifique se o nome da instância está correto e se o SQL Server está configurado para permitir conexões remotas. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - O computador remoto recusou a conexão de rede.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Erro: 1225)

Para obter ajuda, clique em: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=1225&LinkId=20476

---

O computador remoto recusou a conexão de rede

---

BOTÕES:

### OK

`

Comment: A pergunta mais comum: Já reiniciou o servidor? Já que não forneceu demais detalhes como, se tem conectividade (um ping tem resposta), ou ainda se os serviços do MSSQL estão ativos, nos informe.

Comment: Você chegou a altera o nome da sua máquina ? Chegou a verificar o nome da Server name ?

Comment: Deu certo aqui pessoal! era só habilitar uma função aqui!